# Receive/Load user data after login C# WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

After successful login to application i want to get other data from sql of that user like: name, surname, birthdate  etc. and put it into dashboard.sellerinfo.Text;

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DBconnection con1 = new DBconnection();

        try
        {
            con1.connection();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Seller WHERE Login=@Login and Password=@Password";
            SqlCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1.con);
            Sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", login.Text);
            Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password.Password);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(Sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());          

            if(count==1)
            {

                MainWindow dashboard = new MainWindow();
                dashboard.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect.");
                password.Clear();
                login.Clear();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            con1.close();
        }
    }
```

I tried a lot with reader but something went wrong. Do you have any advice? Thanks

Comment: It seems like you are storing passwords in plaintext. Don't do that...
What exactly went wrong? Whích errors do you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ExecuteScalar()` when you intend to select data from the table. You could for example load the entire result set into a `DataTable` using the `ExecuteReader()` method:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Seller WHERE Login=@Login and Password=@Password";
SqlCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1.con);
Sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", login.Text);
Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password.Password);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader());


if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    string name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    //...
    MainWindow dashboard = new MainWindow();
    dashboard.Show();
        this.Hide();
}
...
```

You can then access any column of the first row of the populated `DataTable` like this where "Name" corresponds to a column named "Name" in the "Seller" table:

```
dt.Rows[0]["Name"]
```